# Square with hinge on all four sides

Tags: design, motion

I want to make a component that will be a square plate that will behave like it has a motorized hinge on all four sides. That is, it can "open" by pivoting around any one of its four sides. I want it to pivot by up to 45 degrees.

I thought about designing it so that 3 hinges could be detached while one pivots, but I wonder if there's a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Capitalizing on the 'behave like' section of the question, how about a box apparatus - lid and hinge mechanism on one side - which rotates? Eg open box, close, rotate box 90 degrees, repeat.

Comment: That's a good idea, but with my intended application it might be tough to implement. I'll look into it though.

Comment: Maybe: hang the plate from 4 strings, one attached to each corner, each one with a motorized winch. When you want it to act like it's turning around a hinge on one edge, wind up the 2 winches attached to the opposite side.

Comment: @DavidCary interesting idea. I suppose I could do a similar thing with four linear actuators inside the box. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try having four lids on top of each other.

- The top lid solid and hinged to the lid below.
- The second lid a hollow frame hinged to the lid below 90$^{\circ}$ offset
- The third lid a hollow frame hinged to the lid below 90$^{\circ}$ offset
- The fourth lid a hollow frame hinged to the box 90$^{\circ}$ offset

Comment: You can visualize this by folding a piece of paper: http://i.stack.imgur.com/o4p2Z.jpg

Comment: I didn't envision opening all the lids at once, but yes it would look like this if you did.